# Basic Google Sheet Formula Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Column G : `=if(and(E2<>"",F2=""),"Running","")`

Column H : `=Mod(E2, 1)`

Column I : `=Mod(F2, 1)`

Column J : `=if(F2="","",I2-H2)`

I am using the above as formulas in each cell of the mentioned column, but I have no way of protecting column G, H, I and J from myself the owner of the sheet. Or do I?

My solution would be to create a script to do these functions. Any help on how this could be done?

I was able to solve the first problem, Column G, with:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Timesheet" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
       if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
       if( nextCell.getValue() != '' ) //is not empty?
         nextCell.setValue("");
      else if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue("Running");
      else nextCell.setValue("");
      if( r.getColumn() == 1 )  //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(-1, 6);
        if( nextCell.getValue() != '' ) //is empty?
          nextCell.setValue("");
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Instead of "reinventing the wheel" use a script to add the formulas that should not be changed.

## Explanation

The following script will overwrite cells in columns H, I, J & K from the row 2 with the corresponding formula if any user change them. Note that R1C1 notation is used instead of A1.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  if (col >= 7 && col <= 10) {
    var row = range.getRow();
    if (row > 1) {
      switch (col) {
        case 7: // Column H
          range.setFormulaR1C1('=if(and(R[0]C[-2]<>"",R[0]C[-1]=""),"Running","")');
          break;
        case 8: // Column I
          range.setFormulaR1C1('=Mod(R[0]C[-3], 1)');
          break;
        case 9: // Column J
          range.setFormulaR1C1('=Mod(R[0]C[-3], 1)');
          break;
        case 10: // Column K
          range.setFormulaR1C1('=if(R[0]C[-4]="","",R[0]C[-2]-R[0]C[-1])');
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```